# How to use my Apple Keyboard on Windows 10?

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have a Apple keyboard very similar to this one (I never had a Mac, but these keyboards are really good in keying with a very smooth touch), but it only partially works on Windows 10.
This Apple keyboard I have has a Portuguese layout and I selected in Windows the Portuguese QWERTY layout input, but many keys, like diacritics for example, don't map.

Is there any driver or tool for Windows 10 to perfectly integrate these Apple Keyboards?

[image]

Comment: I've used KeyTweak for 10+ years to use my Mac keyboard with my Windows machines (I use the same keyboard w/ my Mac too, with a USB switcher to connect it to whichever computer I want to use).  I'm in the US, so can't speak to the diacritics, but you can definitely map those Mac keys into ANYTHING you want with KeyTweak, you just might need to loop up some keycodes for those diacritics.

Comment: @jimtut can you provide a more detailed answer such that I set it as solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [repo](https://github.com/stroebjo/autohotkey-windows-mac-keyboard) was the solution

- Install [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), version `1.1.x`
- Run the `MacKeyboard.ahk` file (save the file as UTF8 with BOM)
- Put the `MacKeyboard.ahk` file or a shortcut to the file in your Autostart folder to run it automatically on startup.

Answer (score 1):

Copying my original comment to an answer, and adding some details.

I've used KeyTweak for 10+ years to use my Mac keyboard with my Windows machines (I use the same keyboard w/ my Mac too, with a USB switcher to connect it to whichever computer I want to use). I'm in the US, so can't speak to the diacritics, but you can definitely map those Mac keys into ANYTHING you want with KeyTweak, you just might need to loop up some keycodes for those diacritics.

This picture is the KeyTweak (yeah, it's old and ugly, but it works just fine), and shows how I've mapped my US keyboard for a Mac to Windows, basically swapping the Windows and Alt key location so they are the same physical location as most US keyboards for Windows.  I've also added some other keys too, like PrintScreen and volume controls.

It's VERY ease to map keys (bottom of the window), just press the key on your keyboard (like the Mac's Command key) and then pick which key to map it to (like the Alt key).

[image: KeyTweak UI]

Comment: can you just add a direct link to download KeyTweak? Everything I found on google relates to storage centres for programs and sometimes they install their own stuff attached. It's for my professional PC and I must be sure that what I install is fully safe. thanks

Comment: https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/KeyTweak.shtml and various other SW download sites

Comment: but do you get the program _directly_, or do you have to use their wrapper? The majority SW download sites oblige you to download their "download SW center". I really cannot risk to install garbage on my computer, because it's not mine, it is from the company with a lot of sensible info.

Comment: Yeah, I’ve never used one of those SW Downloaders either, don’t recommend it. I got mine YEARS ago, so I can’t tell you where. Just pick one of the reputable SW sites, and click thru until it lets you skip their downloader, they should let you download directly too.