# Remap Magic Keyboard Keys for Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, mac, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have a MAC keyboard and I'm currently using it on a Windows 10 machine. I have sucessfully mapped the `command` button as `ALT` and `alt/option` key to `Windows Key` so that it would be similar like a windows keyboard. I am currently using "SharpKeys" to map the key but I couldn't map the `fn` key which is at the bottom left edge on my keyboard. I want that key to act like `CTRL` but I'm unable to do so.
And I want the `eject` key to mapped as `Print Screen` key.

I tried doing it so on "SharpKeys" **Type Key** option but it was unable to detect the keys and I do not know for which key value to assign the `ctrl` and `print sc`.

I have attached the picture of my keyboard so that you guys would know what I'm taking about. The green sign shows that I was able to map the following keys to the desired one and the red one is for the one that I couldn't.
[image: keyboard image]

I do know that I have a dedicated `CONTROL` key but I want to map the `fn` key to `ctrl` so I would have the same feelings as using a window keyboard.

Comment: If it is the same as a laptop's FN key then the BIOS controls it and it is not part of the keyboard spec.

Comment: Fn [+ other key] is pre-combined before it leaves the keyboard. It's unlikely you can remap it as a single key. Eject on a Mac is intercepted before even a key-code reader can see it, so I can't tell what it sends. Fn itself sends this data, if you can find something to interpret that - https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2ko1.png

Comment: Duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1599344/how-to-use-my-apple-keyboard-on-windows-10/1600155.  See my answer there.  Although I haven't specifically mapped the Fn key (or key combo's) in Windows, I assume it will work like the rest in the tool recommended there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use my Apple Keyboard on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1599344/how-to-use-my-apple-keyboard-on-windows-10)

Comment: @jimut No, I have tried that and it didn't work. it works with other keys but now with Fn and Eject key. [Key Tweak Logs](https://imgur.com/a/d1E54Sg). Posted a picture of keytweak with logs

Comment: There is no Fn key on keyboards. It is a toggle that allows some of the keys to act as two keys. It is valid only to the keyboard hardware. Nothing happens if you press it from the computer's perspective. If I press F11 then F11 is sent to Windows. If I press Fn+F11 then the volume up key is sent to Windows. At no stage is Fn sent to Windows.

Comment: A Japanese JIS keyboard is your best bet.